# unexpected lock on index in mssql in select queries

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, sql-server-2008, database-deadlocks

I keep getting

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction (Process ID 61) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

So i turned on the mssql logging using

```
DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1)
DBCC TRACEON(1204,-1)
```

and following deadlock info is printed in logs:

These line indicate that a deadlock has been detected, and process 1 has been chosen as victim.

```
process-list
deadlock victim=PROCESS_ID_1
deadlock-list
```

---

**Logs of process_id_1**

```
   [1] (@P0 nvarchar(4000))select namesequen0_.id as id1_47_<c/> namesequen0_.container_id as containe9_47_<c/> namesequen0_.increment_ as incremen2_47_<c/> namesequen0_.nextValue as nextValu3_47_<c/> namesequen0_.numChars as numChars4_47_<c/> namesequen0_.padChar as padChar5_47_<c/> namesequen0_.scope as scope6_47_<c/> namesequen0_.sequenceType as sequence7_47_<c/> namesequen0_.uppercase as uppercas8_47_ from NameSequence namesequen0_ where (namesequen0_.scope like  @P0 ) and (namesequen0_.container_id is null)        
    [2] frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=40 sqlhandle=0x020000005734e00acfb3060d49cc0e8565acb3b105807744
    [3] executionStack
    [4] process id=PROCESS_ID_1 taskpriority=0 logused=1248 waitresource=KEY: 14:72057594053459968 (95c9fddfaf17) waittime=3506 ownerId=13645568 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2015-06-02T07:52:41.660 XDES=0xa30dd950 lockMode=S schedulerid=1 kpid=1848 status=suspended spid=68 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2015-06-02T07:52:41.663 lastbatchcompleted=2015-06-02T07:52:41.660 clientapp=jTDS hostname=QALAB6 hostpid=123 loginname=qalab6_nrm isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=13645568 currentdb=14 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
```

**Logs of process_id_2**

```
[1]select card0_.id as id2_77_<c/> card0_.autoDisplayName as autoDisp3_77_<c/> card0_.autoPartialName as autoPart4_77_<c/> card0_.namedWithSequence_id as namedWi38_77_<c/> card0_.namedWithSequenceValue as namedWit5_77_<c/> card0_.userDisplayName as userDisp6_77_<c/> card0_.userPartialName as userPart7_77_<c/> card0_.lifeCycleState_id as lifeCyc40_77_<c/> card0_.model_id as model41_77_<c/> card0_.outOfService as outOfSe12_77_<c/> card0_.bottomClearance as bottomC13_77_<c/> card0_.leftClearance as leftCle14_77_<c/> card0_.rightClearance as rightCl15_77_<c/> card0_.topClearance as topClea16_77_<c/> card0_.ncmElementKey as ncmElem24_77_ from VfdItem card0_ where card0_.DTYPE='Card' and card0_.ncmElementKey= @P0
[2]frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=40 sqlhandle=0x02000000386ba721896ce39b0b7c9d01df11539c0d843c83
[3]executionStack
[4]process id=PROCESS_ID_2 taskpriority=0 logused=62048 waitresource=KEY: 14:72057594051297280 (fadae9b0c9d3) waittime=3333 ownerId=13645330 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2015-06-02T07:52:39.570 XDES=0xbf9f5950 lockMode=S schedulerid=1 kpid=5344 status=suspended spid=66 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2015-06-02T07:52:41.833 lastbatchcompleted=2015-06-02T07:52:41.813 clientapp=jTDS hostname=QALAB6 hostpid=123 loginname=qalab6_nrm isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=13645330 currentdb=14 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
```

---

Now following line gives details of process_id_1,

Ref[1] is the query that we want to execute...Note: its a select query on a table name `NameSequence` and `namesequence0_.container_id` is a foreign key from a table name `vfditem`.

Ref[4] says that it is waiting for a resource and is suspended

---

Now following line give details of `process_id_2` which is in deadlock with `process_id_1`

Ref[1] Give the query `process_id_2` want to run...Note its a select query on a table name `vfditem` and `card0_.namedWithSequence_id` is a foreign key from table name `NameSequence`

Ref[4] says that it is waiting for a resource and is suspended

---

Now following lines prints all the resource that are locked and by whom and who are waiting for that resource.

```
[11] waiter id=PROCESS_ID_2 mode=S requestType=wait
[10] waiter-list
[9] owner id=PROCESS_ID_1 mode=X
[8] owner-list
[7] keylock hobtid=72057594051297280 dbid=14 objectname=qalab6_nrm.dbo.vfditem indexname=vfditem_pk id=lock85330d00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594051297280
[6] waiter id=PROCESS_ID_1 mode=S requestType=wait
[5] waiter-list
[4] owner id=PROCESS_ID_2 mode=X
[3] owner-list
[2] keylock hobtid=72057594053459968 dbid=14 objectname=qalab6_nrm.dbo.namesequence indexname=NameSequence_PK id=lock848c3380 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594053459968
[1] resource-list
```

This translates to that

[1] the resource `qalab6_nrm.dbo.namesequence indexname=NameSequence_PK` is locked by `process_id_2` in exclusive lock mode and `process_id_1` is waiting on it.

[2] the resource `qalab6_nrm.dbo.vfditem indexname=vfditem_pk` is locked by `process_id_1` in exclusive lock mode and `process_id_2` is waiting on it.

---

**BINGO** We can see how its been deadlocked

---

**NOW the weird part**

If we look closely `process_id_1` is trying to run a select query from a table name `NameSequence` and column `NameSequence.container_id` is foreign key from table `vfditem` and `process_id_1` has already acquired a lock on `indexname=vfditem_pk of vfditem table`

**[1] Why would `process_is_1` acquire a lock on index of vfditem ?**

further `process_id_2` is trying to run a select query from a table name `vfditem` and column `vfditem.namesequence_id` is foreign key from table `NameSequence` and `process_id_2` has already acquired a lock on `indexname=NameSequence_PK  of Namesequence table`

**[2] Why would `process_is_2` acquire a lock on index of Namesequence?**

Comment: In a default installation readers block writers and writers block readers in SQL Server. I would suspect that the sessions are also modifying some rows which can lead to such a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL uses locking on select statements, it can do table, page and row locks. It really depends on what you want to do in your system and what is more important but a good pointer along the way is to look at the [Table Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) that you can put on a SELECT statement, especially looking at `NOWAIT`, `NOLOCK`, `READCOMMITTED` and `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`

You may also want to consider setting the [Isolation Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) on all of your transactions to avoid this issue in other places.

This is some pretty basic information and a DBA may be able to provide a more detailed answer, but these options will prevent that issue from happening

You can tell your isolation level by running `DBCC useroptions` and you can tell the read_committed_snapshot by running `SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name= 'YourDatabase'`

Comment: what you are saying is good... but why did select queries of two different table taking lock on indexes of each other.

Comment: TBH a DBA would be able to give you more information on the why of it all, but basically it locks rows and pages of data, from what you are saying it has probably got two queries blocking each other from selecting from the same piece of data in a table.

Comment: When we had this problem one query was locking a page and another was doing an index lookup on a row.  The underlying problem though is still the same, it is trying to select the same piece of information at the same time and it deadlocks. It should be an easy fix by changing your isolation level or using the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` flag on your database.

Comment: If you include the two queries and the table definitions, it should show a bit more on why. If you look into those logs you will probably also see that there should be something about a page or a row lock for each of those processes. Chances are though that it will not be easy to reproduce.

Comment: queries  are already included in logs and i have described which column is foreign from which table

Comment: Ok, I will just edit that to make it a little clearer. One interesting thing is that your locks have a [`mode=X`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) this is an exclusive lock, done when doing modifications of data. Maybe that same process is running more in the transaction, you might want to look into that further

Comment: "Maybe that same process is running more in the transaction"... yep i also think that, but log only print dead lock info , so any idea on how to get all queries run during that transaction

Comment: The other thing that you should note is that those two queries aren't locking the same object ID, Is there anything more in that 1222 log that you are not showing?

Comment: "so any idea on how to get all queries run during that transaction" - Yes, if you make sure that your transactions are either using the `NOLOCK`/`READUNCOMMITTED` or the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT `(with `READCOMMITTED`) options you won't get SELECT locks like this.

Comment: "those two queries aren't locking the same object ID".. yep that is true..what is happening is process_id_1 takes a lock on "indexname=vfditem_pk" and process_id_2 takes a lock on " indexname=NameSequence_PK".. now process_id_1 want to take lock on " indexname=NameSequence_PK" and process_id_2 want to take lock on ""indexname=vfditem_pk".. and hence the deadlock

Comment: "Is there anything more in that 1222 log that you are not showing?" no.. i have just removed all the timestamps